# why isn't "function" considered a datatype in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The datatypes listed in MSDN for javascript are Number, String, Boolean, Object, Array, Null, Undefined. However, when you do `typeof function`, its type is function.

Why is this the case, and what's the definition of datatype?

Comment: That list is essentially meaningless.  Arrays are regular objects.

Comment: "datatype" isn't even a term used by [the JavaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).

Comment: `typeof` is special and doesn't actually return the type of the value (according to the spec). It's just a lookup table: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Comment: `Function` is as much a data type as `Array` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are just Objects in JavaScript. But the difference lies in an internal property called [`[[Call]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1) that differentiates them from normal Objects. When `typeof` is used against an Object, and if it finds the `[[Call]]` property, then it returns the String "function".

This behavior can be found in the [ECMA Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) for `typeof`.

Comment: Are you saying `typeof { Call: function(){ } }` should return `function`?

Comment: @Luizgrs http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1 - `[[Call]]` is an internal property

Comment: with the specs it's now clear, I thought that brackets meant something but I couldn't understand, now it's fine..